# Email gets stuck in outlook outbox when sending via python script

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

The script can send emails, however if I don't keep outlook open the email gets stuck in outlook 2015 outbox. Even if I have it open it takes 4-5 minutes to finally send. Issue here is that I want it as a scheduled task on a remote desktop, thus I won't be logged in to outlook on the machine. Issue persists w/ or w/o attachments.

```
import win32com.client
import time
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
    
    const=win32com.client.constants
    olMailItem = 0x0
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    newMail.Subject = "subject here"
    newMail.BodyFormat = 2 
    cnt = cnt
    SENDER = "email"
    RECIPIENTS = ["email list"]
    newMail.HTMLBody = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>There are {cnt} new repricing files uploaded. <br>
           <br>
           ~Sent via Python Code
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """.format(cnt=cnt)
    
    attachment = "file.xlsx"
    newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    newMail.To = "; ".join(RECIPIENTS)
    newMail.display()
    time.sleep(5)
    newMail.Send()
```

after `newMail.send()` is called, outlook automatically closes which is nice, but this results in the email getting stuck in outbox.

Comment: As you said, I only could work around it by commenting out the ```newMail.display()``` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Session.SendAndReceive` method. Keep in mind that the process is asynchronous. You can use `SyncObject.SyncEnd` event if you need to wait for the send/receive to finish.

Comment: Could you please give more context on how I incorporate this into the above code? I have tried calling ```Session.SendAndRecieve``` onto the ```newMail object```, but am getting an attribute error. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, actually I realized the issue. When I removed ```newMail.display()``` it works fine. Must be a bug when combining the two calls.